# Extensions of $A_5$ by $C_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology, group-extensions

I'm attempting the following exercise:

> Prove that there are only three finite groups whose composition factors are $A_5$ and $C_2$.
>
> 1. The direct product $A_5 \times C_2$.
> 2. The symmetric group $S_5$.
> 3. A central extension of $A_5$ by $C_2$ known as the binary icosahedral group.

I've completed parts 1 and 2. For part 3, I'm trying to look at extensions of the form:

$$1 \to C_2 \to G \to A_5 \to 1$$

Is there any straightforward argument to show that there cannot exist a non-central split extension of this form? Furthermore, I would be interested in knowing if there is any neat way to show that the unique non-split central extension of $A_5$ by $C_2$ is isomorphic to $I_{120}$. (@DerekHolt gave some hints in the comments.)

Comment: If there is a normal subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$, then an element outside of $A_5$ either induces an inner automorphism of $A_5$, in which case the group $G$  is $A_5 \times C_2$, or not, in which case $G  \le {\rm Aut}(A_5) = S_5$, so $G \cong S_5$. The other possibility is $|Z(G)|=2$ and $G$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$. In that case $G$ is isomorphic to the binary icosahedral group, but I don't know any way to prove that without using the theory of Schur Multipliers, or cohomology groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt  If you could write such a solution, that would be greatly appreciated.  And from the OP's comment above, I think the OP would appreciate it as well.

Comment: But this is an exercise for the OP, so I don't want to write a solution. The Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_5$ is $C_2 \times C_2$, which has Schur Multiplier of order $2$. So the $2$-part of the Schur Multiplier of $A_5$ has order at most $2$. So there is at most one perfect central extension of $A_5$ of order $2$, and since we know there does exist one, it must be unique.

Comment: I don't know a neat way to show that a central extension must be isomorphic to $I_5$, but a normal subgroup of order $2$ is any group is necessarily in the centre of that group, and so any such extension must be a central extension.